# Api angular for calendar events

Tags: jquery, angularjs, calendar, angular-ui-bootstrap, daypilot

I would like to use a full open source calendar API for angularJs 1.5.0.

I integrated Daypilot Pro to my app but it is a trial version. With DayPilot lite miss many feature like OnEventClicked.

Is there any other API open source i can use? or is there someone worked with Daypilote lite with OnEventClicked feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other option you can use angular full calendar of jquery 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/blob/master/README.md
 It has lots of examples and easy to use.